# Relation between the $U(1)$ symmetry and the excitation number operator in quantum optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, hamiltonian, quantum-optics

Firstly, we consider the Hamiltonian of Jaynes-Cummings model, i.e.,
$$H=\omega_c a^\dagger a + \omega_e\sigma^\dagger \sigma + g(a^\dagger \sigma+\sigma^\dagger a).$$
Obviously, it satisfies the $U(1)$ symmetry, and we can find the total excitation number operator $N$,
$$N=a^\dagger a+\sigma^\dagger \sigma,$$
which commutes with the Hamiltonian (i.e., $[H, N]=0$).

Then, we consider the other Hamiltonian involving two bosonic modes, i.e.,
$$H=\omega_aa^\dagger a+\omega_bb^\dagger b+g(a^\dagger b^2+b^{\dagger 2}a).$$
Similarly, the Hamiltonian also satisfies the $U(1)$ symmetry, and we also can find a operator $\tilde{N}$,
$$\tilde{N}=2a^\dagger a+b^\dagger b,$$
which commutes with the Hamiltonian, i.e.,
\begin{align}
[H,2a^\dagger a+b^\dagger b]&=g[a^\dagger b^2,2a^\dagger a+b^\dagger b]+g[b^{\dagger 2}a,2a^\dagger a+b^\dagger b]\\
&=g(-2a^\dagger b^2+2a^\dagger b^2)+g(2b^{\dagger 2}a-2b^{\dagger 2}a)\\
&=0=[H,\tilde{N}].
\end{align}

Finally, my question is: can the operator $\tilde{N}$ also be called the total excitation number operator? if not, what is the physical meaning of the operator?

Comment: Why do you have a factor of 2 in $\tilde{N}$?

Comment: how does $a^\dagger b^2$ , which changes the total number of excitations, commute with $\hat N$?

Comment: @flippiefanus You can see the revised version.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Look at the new derivation steps.

Comment: Thanks for the calculation showing the commutation between $H$ and $\tilde{N}$. It is now easy to see that the 2 is unnecessary. The Hamiltonian commutes separately with $a^{\dagger}a$ and $b^{\dagger}b$. Each of these can therefore be interpreted as a number operator for the associated field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* call your $\hat N$ the total excitation number operator.  The total number of excitation is $n_a+n_b$, not $2n_a+n_b$.

You need the factor of $2$ there in your $\hat N$ because you are creating two $b$-excitations for every $a$-excitation you remove, so you need to count twice every $a$-excitation to keep $\hat N$ constant.

The unusual thing is that the number of $b$-excitations must be odd or even when the eigenvalue $n$ of $\hat N$ is odd or even.  For instance, if the eigenvalue of $\hat N$ is $7$, then the number of $b$-excitations can only be odd.  Thus, the space of states with eigenvalue $n=7$ of your operator $\hat N$ is spanned by the vector $\vert n_a,n_b\rangle$ in the set $\{\vert 0,7\rangle,\vert 1,5\rangle, \vert 2,3\rangle,\vert 3,1\rangle\}$.  Clearly, they do not all have the same total number of excitations.

Your $\hat N$ is just a constant that allows you to identify subspaces invariant under your Hamiltonian.  It doesn’t have a particular name, although clearly its eigenstates are not related to the total number of excitations.

Comment: Thank you very much.